# Creating Scheduler App - process and concept questions

Tags: php, mysql

*If there are other times this has been asked or answered, I apologize - I think my searches keep getting lost in people who are trying to schedule PHP tasks on a server so I'm not finding what I am looking for.*

So as my first self-built app (not a guided or instructed one) I am trying to build a camp scheduling program.  I have things already built to login, add cabins/groups or remove them, add activities/groups or remove them, and to generate a date range, and from that data, to select which of those things you want to schedule for and then send it to a scheduler which then creates a new MySQL table and...

This is where I keep stopping and wondering If I'm thinking about this correctly.

- Should each new run of a schedule create a new table - is this
  scalable (it doesn't matter for me if its scalable for this, but it
  does matter for other projects, obviously)?
- Should I do sorting with arrays before I ever enter data into the
  MySQL table,  or can I enter consecutively and then enter the next
  item as its being sorted?

Ultimately, I cannot do only a round-robin, because I need to add other factors like:

- Has this group done this activity in the last X number of scheduled periods? If so, choose another one.
- Do not always start from the top of the activities list, otherwise some activities will always be schedule and some will always be the first to be left empty - maybe even be able to prioritize the importance given some factors.
- Initially I just want to schedule the activities for the dates with the groups, but I'd also like to add a feature to be able to factor in another schedule (canoe trips that cabins take) to exclude them from the scheduled list for the days they will be gone.

Any help I can get with the sorting logic is appreciated.  Thanks.

**Edit:**
So based on your suggestion, I am thinking that I have the following tables with only two columns for ID and name (can be updated/edited by the user at any time):

```
cabins
activities
```

I then add another table which has up to, say, 56 columns for date entries (8 weeks) + a name and user column called:

```
dates
```

Then I have another table called:

```
schedule
```

which has columns like this:

```
ID (primary Key)
User (logged in user that created this)
schedule_name (user defined name of schedule)
cabin (foreign key of a cabin)
period_001 (foreign key of first date in corresponding 'dates' table)
activity_001 (foreign key of an available activity which has been chosen to go here)
period_002 (...)
activity_003 (...)
etc...
```

Then the PHP logic will ask for rows grouped by name and user, so that for each schedule name for a given user, there would be one row for every selected cabin in camp (ex. 25 rows for 25 cabins).  And each row in the 'dates' table contains the entire date range for a given schedule.

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: This might be more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ as it does't reference a specific solvable problem and so isn't a good fit for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Danack: No, actually it does. It's not a conceptual programming question, it is a practical one. Not all questions on [so] need to have code.

Comment: Seems kind of "how do I model my data" rather than "how do I code this" to me. But don't close it just yet, I'm drafting an answer... ;)

Comment: I think it's a bit of both, TBH.  If we get a step further maybe I can rehash with more code examples.

Comment: @IMSoP: It's not "how do I model my data" rather than "how do I approach to working with this data when I have the following rules?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is a database modelling question. To start with your specific questions:

> Should each new run of a schedule create a new table?

No. A table represents a *type* of thing (as would a class in an OO implementation). If you need to distinguish groups of rows in that table, then that is an attribute of those rows, and probably a separate entity in its own right. So you would have a table with a row for each "new run of a schedule", and then refer to that in your other table with a Foreign Key.

> Should I do sorting with arrays before I ever enter data into the MySQL table?

No. The order rows are entered into a database table should never be used to impart meaning. If they have some particular order, the information to create that order should be in a column of the table. You sort data when you *retrieve* it from the database, using an `Order By` clause. (**Always** include an `Order By` clause whenever you are `Select`ing data.)

Your second set of bullet points seems to jump from how to *model* the data to how to *query* it. So first, read up on:

- Database Normalization: in brief, every entity should have its own table, and the relationships between them defined by Foreign Keys
- Entity-Relationship Diagrams: don't worry about learning all the official symbols, but drawing out your data on a Visio diagram or a piece of paper can really help understand how things relate

Once you have a decent idea of what your entities are, and a normalised structure for them, the rest should just be about how to write queries relating to them:

- "Has this group done this activity in the last X number of scheduled periods?" might involve a `JOIN` between a `groups` table, a `groups_scheduled_activities` pivot table (i.e. one that exists only to relate two or more tables in a many-to-many relationship), and a `scheduled_periods` table.
- "Do not always start from the top of the activities list ... maybe even be able to prioritize the importance" is all about how you select from the `activities` table when you're displaying it in the UI: perhaps an `Order By` clause involving your priority factors and a random factor. (Random ordering in some DBs can be tricky, but look around and you'll find plenty of solutions.)
- If I understand right, "factor in another schedule to exclude them from the scheduled list for the days they will be gone" would just be a particular kind of "activity" that lasted a long time and maybe was presented differently in the UI. From a data modelling point of view, this just needs an attribute on activities (i.e. a column on the `activities` table) to distinguish these from "normal" activities. Presumably, activities would have a "duration" attribute anyway.

Comment: OK, I edited to include planned changes - is this what you were thinking?  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @red6 The suggestions in your edit include a lot of columns where they should have rows - you're trying to squeeze multiple things into one table. You also mention having a table to store dates, which will generally be unnecessary, because you can just use the date itself. I've put together [a quick example of a normalised schema](https://gist.github.com/IMSoP/6653849) based on what you've mentioned so far.

Comment: I've implemented most of your suggestions and am working on finishing it today.  Your last bullet point was correct, if I think of it as a 'hidden' activity, or one that is presented elsewhere, it can just be stored the same way.